# Action script3 trace in flex builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

this is the code, i am using flex builder 4.5,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 

           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public var ss:Array = ["a", "b", "c"];
        trace(ss[0]);
        public var str:String = "Good Luck";
        trace(str);


    ]]>
</fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

i get red cross next to trace statment and fault is

"1120:Access of defined property ss"

i have tried the commented line as well but no luck. i have tried with 3.5, 4.1 and 4.5 sdk.
Am i missing something? please guide!!
(i tried googling it but nothing came up )

thanks in advance. 
(updated the code)

Comment: Is this inside a mxml <script> tag, is it a class or As file ? can you post the entire code ?
I can have the trace running just fine.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
 <fx:Declarations>
  <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
 </fx:Declarations>
 <fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   public var ss:Array = ["a", "b", "c"];
   trace(ss[0]);

   
  ]]>
 </fx:Script>
</s:Application>               i dont know how to enter code in the post sorry about the mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public var ss:String` is a field declaration and `trace(ss)` is an action in code execution flow. Place `trace(ss)` in an appropriate scope (in a function aka method) and it will be compiled and executed without any problem.

Comment: without method it cannot be called, that is not good. could be a sdk fault

Comment: Why not good? It is good OOP way to place your code in methods.

Comment: But if just want to trace a simple varible then i have to write a function and excute to use the 'trace' to get its value, isnt it overkill to use one built-in function of actionscript.

Comment: Value of property can't be set from nowhere. So if you want to trace its value just place `trace` statement in an appropriate method which related to the program event which set the value. If we are talking about tracing of values of field with in-place initializing the appropriate event can be `preinitialize`. Or constructor for AS classes.

Comment: And please don't complain about this. If you dislike it you can switch to scripting languages like JavaScript. But ActionScript 3 is more OOP language than AS 2 or 1. Sorry about that.

Comment: First of all i hate javascript, but i must say if i use the same code in the flash cs4 it works fine. why?

Comment: As far as I know Flash converts code in frames into methods automatically. Flex hasn't that frame conception but only has text sources which are classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting confused between Class member properties and local variables.  Inside a method, you can only declare local variables, for example:

```
public function debugString() : void {
    // declare a local property, only this, 'debugString' function can acess
    // or modify this property - it is deleted when this function finishes.
    var myString : String = "Hello World";
    trace(myString);
}
```

However, it would appear that you were trying to define Class member properties instead (because you were declaring the visibility of the property (ie: public)).

```
public class HelloWorld {
    // Define a Class member property; all functions in this Class will be
    // able to access, and modify it.  This property will live for as long as the
    // Class is still referenced.
    public var myString : String = "Hello World";

    public function debugString() : void {
        // notice how we did not declare the 'myString' variable inside 
        // this function.
        trace(myString);
    }
}
```

Note that you can only access member properties once a Class has been constructed; so the earliest you can (sensibly) access them is in your Constructor, for example:

```
class HelloWorld {
    public var myString : String = "Hello World";

    // This will not work, because you can only access static properties
    // outside of a function body.  This makes sense because a member property
    // belongs to each instance of a given Class, and you have not constructed
    // that instance yet.
    trace(myString);

    // This is the Class Constructor, it will be called automatically when a
    // new instance of the HelloWorld class is created.
    public function HelloWorld() {
        trace(myString);
    }
}
```

What you might be trying to do is make use of a static property; these differ from Class member properties as they are Globally shared amongst all instances of a given class.  By convention, static properties are defined in CAPS:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    // Here we define a static property; this is accessible straight away and you
    // don't even need to create a new instance of the host class in order to 
    // access it, for example, you can call HelloWorld.MY_STRING from anywhere in your
    // application's codebase - ie: trace(HelloWorld.MY_STRING)
    public static var MY_STRING : String = "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: So YOu are saying that trace has to be in the function to be called not be called without function

Comment: static initialiser ? i dont know about it. but if i use this code in flash cs4 it works fine. is it differnet actionscript3?

Comment: In the Flash IDE (also referred to as Flash Professional); all ActionScript written in the "Actions" Panel is inserted into a pseudo function (in a process known as FrameScript).